# Django: How to mock file uploads while testing views

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I want to unit test my view. The view is supposed to get images from the form, upload them to Amazon S3 and finally show previews of the uploaded images.

I'd like to ask anybody for a complete example of:

1. How to write a unit test for the view.
2. How and what to mock in the test in order to keep testing speed high.

Answer (score 7):

The view could be tested using `RequestFactory`. That way you skip all the middleware and url resolution that slows your tests down. Note that you'll have to modify the returned `request` object so that all decorators decorating your view function are fine with it.

When testing you could provide a dummy storage for tests so that S3 wouldn't be hit, and provide a 1x1 image file so that `PIL` won't scream it doesn't look like image file (the file could be reused in your other test cases, instead of being programatically created). Or, depending on used client library, mock the `save()` or `_save()` methods of the library of choice's storage object at the point you are doing the actual mocking (perhaps `myapp.models` if using the `storage` kwarg of the `ImageField`, or django internals if using the settings).

```
from django.test.client import RequestFactory
from django.test import TestCase

from myapp import views


class MyViewTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.rq = RequestFactory()

    def test_view(self):
        with open('test_data/test_img.png', 'rb') as img:
            req = self.rq.post('my_view_url', {'my_post': 'data', 'test': 1, 'image': img})
            resp = views.my_view(req)
            # ... asserts ...
```

Comment: Hey @kroolik, thanks for the answer. Is it possible I not to use test files and not to hit db at all? I'd like to make unit testing entirely isolated. Also  could you please expand your answer with mocking example? This is the most interesting part.

Comment: You could mock all the ```model.objects``` and ```model.save``` attributes and methods for models used in your view to avoid hitting the db (beware that some view decorators might still use db). Using ```SimpleTestCase``` prevents django from preparing database for that particular test case.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure you can use this in your context but [SimpleUploadedFile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files-to-a-form) helped me test an upload view without touching the db or file system.

As you can see bellow I have a hardcoded image in code which I use to initialize the `SimpleUploadedFile` object. This way the `SimpleUploadedFile` really behaves like an image since it has a valid binary content and a valid filename.

```
# hex encoded bytes of a tiny valid png file
valid_png_hex = ['\x89', 'P', 'N', 'G', '\r', '\n', '\x1a', '\n', '\x00',
                 '\x00', '\x00', '\r', 'I', 'H', 'D', 'R', '\x00',
                 '\x00', '\x00', '\x01', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x01',
                 '\x08', '\x02', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x90',
                 'w', 'S', '\xde', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x06', 'b', 'K',
                 'G', 'D', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00',
                 '\x00', '\x00', '\xf9', 'C', '\xbb', '\x7f', '\x00', '\x00',
                 '\x00', '\t', 'p', 'H', 'Y', 's', '\x00',
                 '\x00', '\x0e', '\xc3', '\x00', '\x00', '\x0e', '\xc3',
                 '\x01', '\xc7', 'o', '\xa8', 'd', '\x00', '\x00',
                 '\x00', '\x07', 't', 'I', 'M', 'E', '\x07', '\xe0', '\x05',
                 '\r', '\x08', '%', '/', '\xad', '+', 'Z',
                 '\x89', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x0c', 'I', 'D', 'A', 'T',
                 '\x08', '\xd7', 'c', '\xf8', '\xff', '\xff',
                 '?', '\x00', '\x05', '\xfe', '\x02', '\xfe', '\xdc', '\xcc',
                 'Y', '\xe7', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00',
                 'I', 'E', 'N', 'D', '\xae', 'B', '`', '\x82']
valid_png_bin = "".join(valid_png_hex)
png = SimpleUploadedFile("tiny.png", valid_png_bin)
post_data = {u'image': [png], ...}
```

Comment: It works with bytes now: `valid_png_bin = bytes("".join(valid_png_hex), "utf-8")`